# Are simplified elementary proofs if valid interesting to the professional mathematical community

Tags: nt.number-theory, soft-question, prime-numbers, elementary-proofs

For the last 10+ years, as a math amateur, I worked nightly on understanding the distribution of primes and the classic results in the [history of Fermat's Last Theorem](http://fermatslasttheorem.blogspot.com/).

I have made numerous mistakes and for the last seven of those 10+ years, I have, at a rate of once per year, submitted what appeared to me to be valid proofs to the math.stackexchange.com community.  Up until this year, without exception, they were not valid.  In each case, a mistake was found indicating to me that I had much to learn and reminding me to be very thorough before believing that one of my arguments was worthwhile to propose to math.stackexchange.com.

This past week, I have a proposed an [argument](https://mathoverflow.net/q/262400/15915) that was accepted on this web site and a more [ambitious argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2154264/48606) that I am waiting for evaluation where I expect that a mistake has been made.

It occurred to me that the work I am doing may not have any interest to the professional math community.  If someone were to solve a problem such as Legendre's Conjecture using surprisingly simple methods such as arguments from modular arithmetic and standard high school algebraic equations, would this be at all interesting?

Would it be interesting if it greatly simplified a problem that had previously been given a state-of-the-art analytic number theory solution?

In other words, is the professional mathematical community interested in proofs that are valid but which do not extend the methods of mathematical analysis?

Comment: A new proof is always a valid contribution. It may shred a light on the problem from a new angle, that may lead to developments in a new direction. Also, simple proofs are often more illuminating about the reasons why theorems are true than complicated technical ones. Finally, simplicity is the aesthetics of mathematics (IMHO). I am a student though, not sure if I represent the professional mathematical community.

Comment: Thanks @erz.  I have seen great support from graduate students.  I do not see the same support by professional mathematicians in general.  It may be there (I think that they must get tired from all the cranks).  I have, by the way, gotten awesome feedback at times from some rock star mathematicians.  I thought it was worthwhile to ask my question directly and see the responses.  :-)

Comment: I'm myself an amateur and find it difficult to judge the validity and interest of my ideas. I'm essentially interested in Goldbach's conjecture related problems and L-functions but am losing motivation. You can take a glance at my blog ideasfornumbertheory.com and find out if some stuff there catches your attention. Maybe you can make it more rigorous if you feel the need for it.

Comment: Regarding your more ambitious argument, I think you have too much redundancy which obscures the presentation.  Also, I think 2^h divides a is wrong.  I would expect a prime divisor to be 1 more than a multiple of a, which itself leads to a cleaner and more general proof.  Gerhard "But Keep Trying Other Things" Paseman, 2017.02.21.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for the comments!  I will update.

Comment: Something that might be a good exercise in exposition for you: Find (or reprove) results that talk about prime factors of a^n +- b^n.  With few exceptions, there will be a prime factor of this that is 1 more than a multiple of n.  Use this to solve (or restrict) as many cases of Catalan's conjecture as you can. Then write it up for a high school audience, with an appendix that has proofs that can be checked by an undergraduate.  Gerhard "That'll Teach You About Writing" Paseman, 2017.02.21.

Comment: Great suggestion.  I should definitely work on my exposition.  :-) This sounds like a great candidate for a blog post with a target of an MAA participant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think such work is important and has its place.  However, it is not clear that stackexchange is that place.

There are a lot of ideas to be considered.  Where simple algebraic and combinatorial methods are concerned, many of those have been tried and published or discarded.  However, such arguments have an educational value in teaching a student the limitations of such a method and giving that student an appreciation for the subtleties that arise in the subject.  I think it is good to have a repository of such ideas to use in future proofs.

Should such proofs appear on Stackexchange? It depends on the community taste.  I think very very short proofs (such as the sketch I gave of your argument re Sylvester Schur ) fit within the guidelines for MathOverflow, especially if you are asking about one step in the sketch, but the mandate for the forum is for discussion of professional mathematics, and there needs to be more to be a good fit.  Your question was good because it asked about extensions, and my answer provided a reference which is of interest to the research community: anyone else asking about an extension to S-S will see your post, my answer, and the valuable link provided.

If you find a proof, post it somewhere on the web so that those interested will find a link.  Unless it is exceptional and enlightening, its audience will not be professional mathematicians, but others who wish to study and do mathematics.

Gerhard "Speaking As Doer Of Mathematics" Paseman, 2017.02.21.

Comment: As always, thanks for your sincere comments!  I think that your answer is what I expected.  I appreciate your honesty.

Comment: I should also point out that I only post short arguments on stack exchange with the thought that they are valuable to students learning about math and interested in common mistakes made.  :-)

Comment: Indeed.  Speaking as a well meaning critic (which means don't let me spoil your fun), I would recommend using my proof sketch as a guide for terseness, and aim somewhere slightly less brief.  I find many places in your ambitious argument that could be edited out for sake of communication.  I would use my proof sketch as an outline for a student, but filling in each statement, but I have faith in (e.g.) Aaron's mastery that I would consider the sketch sufficient for communicating with him.  Gerhard "Remember Who Your Audience Is" Paseman, 2017.02.21.

Comment: I will try my best to shorten it using your proof sketch as a guide.  :-). Thanks for calling that out!

Comment: I greatly simplified both proofs.  The result seems to hold which suggests to me that the prime version of Catalan's Conjecture is trivial.  As I tried to generalize my approach to the full Catalan Conjecture, not surprisingly, I found that the method fell short.  Thanks for this suggestion!   Regards.

Answer (score 3):

Since you ask, I'm going to offer my opinion, but it is for you to decide how much to consider it. I am going to approach your question as: "I enjoy researching these topics , at the same time I am discouraged by the outcome. Would anyone even care if a simplified proof was found? "

My answer would be: Yes ... But.

**Yes**, A new proof may give new insights and perhaps even open new areas. Even if it does not, it is a joy to find and to see. And just delving into the topic may be rewarding for you if you enjoy it. So at the most positive, it could be enjoyable to try and a new proof is a permanent contribution to mathematics.

**But** How would you feel about the thrill of the chase without ever making a new contribution? You might be fine with it. if not, evaluate the odds. And, if you have been producing work which was not valid without realizing it, that is something to work on if you want to keep it up.

Do you know examples of

*Someone solving a problem such as Legendre's Conjecture using surprisingly simple methods such as arguments from modular arithmetic and standard high school algebraic equations*

And if so, what was the case about the people who found them?

Since you say that you have several attempted proofs with flaws in them and anticipate a flaw in your latest, I'll close with this advice: If this is something you like to do then it sounds like you could strengthen your proof ability. The usual way to do that it to take a course (or several) or work through books with good problems. And that is an activity which gives the joy of doing math.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comments.  I appreciate your thoughts and your response!  I have read enough math books and taken enough classes that all mistakes at this point come down to my tendency to assume that something is obviously true when it is not or my continuous ability to make stupid mistake in my formulas.  I ask this question only to know whether it makes sense for me to try to publish to arxiv.org (assuming that one of my argument holds up) or whether I should restrain my ambitions and stick to entertaining myself and other amateurs.  :-)